# How to add key in registry during setup that points to location of installed EXE

Tags: wix, windows-installer, registrykey

I'm working with Wix 3.7 and as part of the installation of an app I'm working on I need to add a custom shell action to invoke the application for certain file extensions.

Basically, I need to add a key under the `shell` sub-key of certain extensions under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT root tree in the Registry.

I've figured out how to add the key but I haven't been able to modify the value of the key dynamically to point to the exe being installed.

This is what I have:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCR"
                     Key="txt\shell\MyApplicationName"
              Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
            <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="SOME_VALUE" KeyPath="yes"/>
        </RegistryKey>
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Essentially, instead of `SOME_VALUE` I would like it to reference the install folder and the name of the application's EXE, followed by some switches and a parameter. Something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder\MyAppExe.EXE" /a /b "%1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "[#IdentifierOfExeFile]". That's a formatted string and will be replaced with the full path to the target file with specified id. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for the full list of options with formatted strings.

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for.